# Want to get previous value of selected button

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

```
<pre>
   <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" class="form-qty form-control" min="1">
         <div class="quantity-nav">
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty-up">+</div>
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty-down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
<pre>
```

This is loop.

I want to get input value when i click quantity up & down button each time. There are multiple elements.
How to find input value in javascript by clicking button up & down.

Comment: Please provide code so we can somewhat understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Since this is a loop you need to be aware of duplicate id's... Are you able to use jQuery lib ?

Comment: The given coe is not providing any loop. What have you tried to "get input value"? Where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n6dh34zf/  Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onClick` event with `parents` feature to detect the inputs near to the button.

```js
$(document).on('click','.quantity-up',function(){
  $qtyElemnt = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.form-qty');
  $qty = $qtyElemnt.val();
  $qtyElemnt.val(Number($qty)+1);
});

$(document).on('click','.quantity-down',function(){
  $qtyElemnt = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.form-qty');
  $qty = $qtyElemnt.val();
  $qtyElemnt.val(Number($qty)-1);
});
```

```css
.quantity {
   padding: 10px;
}
.quantity-nav{
    display: inline-block;
}
.quantity-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #c7c5c5;
    border: 1px solid #585353;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" name="qty" value="1" class="form-qty form-control" min="1">
         <div class="quantity-nav">
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty-up">+</div>
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty-down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" name="qty" value="1" class="form-qty form-control" min="1">
         <div class="quantity-nav">
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty-up">+</div>
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty-down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" name="qty" value="1" class="form-qty form-control" min="1">
         <div class="quantity-nav">
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty-up">+</div>
              <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty-down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to store the value of your quantity, this would make the `data` persistent.

**Please check the below code snippet:**

```
const down = document.querySelector('.down');
const up = document.querySelector('.up');
const input = document.querySelector('.quantity');

// store utility function
const store = {
  existsIn: function(key) {
    return this.getFromKey(key) !== null;
  },
  getFromKey: function(key) {
    return window.localStorage.getItem(key);
  },
  add: function(key, value) {
    const storeSource = window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
}

const quantity = Object.create(store);

quantity.exists = function() {
  return this.existsIn('quantity');
}

quantity.increase = function() {
  let storedQuantity = this.exists() ? parseFloat(this.getFromKey('quantity')) : 0;
  storedQuantity = storedQuantity + 1;
  this.add('quantity', storedQuantity); 
}

quantity.decrease = function() {
  let storedQuantity = this.exists() ? parseFloat(this.getFromKey('quantity')) : 0;
  if(storedQuantity > 0) {
    storedQuantity = storedQuantity - 1;
  }

  this.add('quantity', storedQuantity);
}

quantity.show = function() {
  return this.exists() ? this.getFromKey('quantity') : 0;
}

// event listeners for up and down buttons 
up.addEventListener('click', function() {
  quantity.increase();

  // update input on button click
  input.value = quantity.show();
})

down.addEventListener('click', function() {
  quantity.decrease();

  // update input on button click
  input.value = quantity.show();
})

// update input on page load
input.value = quantity.show();
```

There you can find a working fiddle:
https://jsbin.com/tavalocoti/5/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is quite easy to solve.
Try to add this script at the end of your `<body>`.
I suggest you to make some modifications in your html too: use `<button>` or `<input type="button"`or even `<a>` tags for your controls.
I added some logic about the min/max/step attributes you can set on a `<input type="number">` but this is optional. It's up to you to change this.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const qtyWraps = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
  for (let i = 0; i < qtyWraps.length; i++) {
    const qtyWrap = qtyWraps.item(i);
    const input = qtyWrap.querySelector('.form-qty');
    const up = qtyWrap.querySelector('.qty-up');
    const down = qtyWrap.querySelector('.qty-down');
    const output = qtyWrap.querySelector('.output');
    up.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addValue(1);
    });
    down.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addValue(-1);
    });
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      output.textContent = input.value
    });
    const addValue = function(value) {
      const current = parseInt(input.value);
      const min = input.getAttribute('min') || -Infinity;
      const max = input.getAttribute('max') || Infinity;
      const step = input.getAttribute('step') || 1;
      const newValue = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, current + value * step));
      input.value = newValue;
      if (newValue <= min) down.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      else down.removeAttribute('disabled');
      if (newValue >= max) up.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      else up.removeAttribute('disabled');
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    }
    addValue(0)
  }
});
```

```css
.quantity {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.quantity .form-qty {
  display: inline-block;
}

.quantity .quantity-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.quantity .output {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
  <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" class="form-qty form-control" min="1">
  <div class="quantity-nav">
    <button class="quantity-button quantity-up qty-up">+</button>
    <button class="quantity-button quantity-down qty-down">-</button>
  </div>
  <!-- I put it here to show the output result -->
  <div class="output">1</div>
</div>
```